# Why does Javascript function execute without waiting for onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
    function hide(c1) {
        document.getElementById(c1).style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = hide("red-circle");
```

When the page loads, the red circle is automatically hidden.  I am trying to understand how to define the "hide" function to call it later while passing the name of the item to be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the code you posted, you are trying to set the onclick event to the return value of the hide function, instead of the hide function itself. Try this:

```
function hide(c1) {
    document.getElementById(c1).style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function(){
    hide("red-circle");
};
```